# knockoutjs change binding at runtime

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, data-binding

please this simple code to illustrate the case :

```
<select id="se">
  <option value="0">EN</option>
  <option value="1">FR</option>
  <option value="2">AR</option>
  <option value="3">SP</option>
</select>  
<input id="inp"  data-bind='textInput: DESCRIPTION_FR' />


<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var PRDVM = function () {
      var self = this;
      self.ID = ko.observable(0);
      self.DESCRIPTION_FR = ko.observable('FR');
      self.DESCRIPTION_EN = ko.observable('EN');
      self.DESCRIPTION_AR = ko.observable('AR');
      self.DESCRIPTION_SP = ko.observable('SP');
      self.IMAGE = ko.observable('/images/noimage.png');
};
ko.applyBindings(new PRDVM());
</script>
```

what i want is to switch the language by changing the property binding of the input at runtime by changing the dropdownlist selection

any idea on how it can be done would be great .

here the starting fiddle
[https://https://jsfiddle.net/smtsghqm/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/smtsghqm/2/)

thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a writable computed property that determines which observable to display/update based on the selected option. The binding would be to the computed and wouldn't have to change.

```js
var PRDVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.SelectedValue = ko.observable();
    self.ID = ko.observable(0);
    self.DESCRIPTION_FR = ko.observable('FR');
    self.DESCRIPTION_EN = ko.observable('EN');
    self.IMAGE = ko.observable('/images/noimage.png');
    
    self.DESCRIPTION = ko.computed({
        read: function(){
            switch(self.SelectedValue()){
                case "0": 
                   return self.DESCRIPTION_EN();
                case "1": 
                   return self.DESCRIPTION_FR();
            }
        },
        write: function(value){
            switch(self.SelectedValue()){
                case "0": 
                   self.DESCRIPTION_EN(value);
                   break;
                case "1": 
                   self.DESCRIPTION_FR(value);
                   break;
            }
        }
    })
};
ko.applyBindings(new PRDVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select id="se" data-bind="value: SelectedValue">
  <option value="0">EN</option>
  <option value="1">FR</option>
  <option value="2">AR</option>
  <option value="3">SP</option>
</select>
<br /><br /><br />
    <input id="inp"  data-bind='textInput: DESCRIPTION' />
```